# Apache Proxy pass and static resources

Tags: apache, proxy

I have two apps running on my localhost and configure proxypass like this

```
ProxyPass /app1 http://192.168.56.102:10001/
ProxyPass / http://192.168.56.102:82/
```

Now when I hit the url  http://192.168.56.102/app1 I have the content of the app1
and if I use  http://192.168.56.102 I have the content of my second app

The app1 index html contains   `<link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet">`
and it dosen’t work correctly because instead of taking the http://192.168.56.102/app1 as base url it uses http://192.168.56.102/ and my ressources cannot load at http://192.168.56.102/style.css because it's not redirected to the right app url and doesn't contain style.css .

On the app2 it work well because the root url is http://192.168.56.102 considering my proxy rules.

So is there a way to achieve what I want ?

When proxying to the app1 use the url for the static content http://192.168.56.102/app1 
if I use `<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">` it work but it is not my app and every static ressources is prefixed with /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your content isn't happy being served from anything but under /, it's not proxy friendly.  You could use mod_rewrite to check HTTP_REFERER and add the /app1 prefix back in prior to your proxy rules.

Comment: I am a newly with apache do you have a tutorial to explain how to achieve what i want because it is particular I need to say when I am in myserver.com/app1 when a static content is loaded using /style.css i need to add /app1 prefix but how do i know that. I do not see how is this possible and on what condition because I can't have at the address myserver.com/style.css a file that exists and is for the second app.

Comment: Sorry, no tutorial to share. You have to understand that http is mostly stateless. You can sometimes see a referer, or a cookie, to indicate context.

Comment: To clarify I need that is the fact that I have a server reachable at a domain name that i buy I only have a domain name let's say :  main.me and my main app which is a node js app is reachable at main.me and i have other services like jenkins gitlab and would like to be able to reach the services using main.me/jenkins or main.me/gitlab and the problem is that thoses services are in a docker containers and listening on the port 8080 or 8084 and when i proxying to the gitlab host for example the resources like css are coded using / and to find the ressources it look at main.me/style.css

Comment: I decided to change url style using jenkins.main.me instead of main.me/jenkins it solves my problem.

Answer (score -1):

u have to create 2 folders in your webapps folder in tomcat  for each project .  tomcat/webapps/ normally u have to be one folder but if u wanna use two project u have to configure server.xml to use both of these . tomcat/conf/server.xml

Comment: actually i am not using tomcat I use one nodejs app and one static site in var/www folder. 

The node js app is reachable at http://192.168.56.102/ and the other app at http://192.168.56.102/app1 i want to have my main app reachable using the serverName directly and the other apps by typing serverName/app1 ...